# Wake up a thread in Python if event occurs

Tags: python, multithreading, firebase

I know questions like this have already been asked, so in a sense, this is a duplicate. However, I've looked at many of those questions, and numerous websites, and I still can't figure out how to do what the title of this question says. This is what I'm trying to accomplish, more specifically:

One thread, `t_sensors`, reads values from a sensor, and after it does so, goes to sleep for `refresh_rate` amount of seconds. This might be a few hours, so during this time it could get a request to read values from the sensor again. This request comes from the thread `t_checker`, which checks for data in a Firebase database, and based on the data, chooses whether or not to wake up `t_sensors`.

```
def start_sensors(self):
     # do some stuff...
     # refreshes every refresh_rate secs
     refresh_rate = firebase_root.get('/settings', 'refreshRate')
     condition.wait(refresh_rate)

 def check_for_plants(self):
     while True:
         modded_plants = firebase_root.get('/modifiedPlants', '')
         print(modded_plants)
         for plant, properties in modded_plants.items():
             print properties['status']
             if properties['status'] == 'modified':
                 condition.notify()
                 print("Notified")

 condition = threading.Condition()
 t_sensors = threading.Thread(target=start_sensors, args=(condition,))
 t_checker = threading.Thread(target=check_for_plants, args=(condition,))
 condition.acquire()
 t_sensors.start()
 t_checker.start()
```

I know I'm not using conditions correctly, at all, but I'm really not sure where I should even start fixing the problem. I'd really, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Check out the [`waiting`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/waiting) library.

Comment: Do you don't want the timer to reset if the t_check wants to check, or like continue on it's cycle?

Comment: @erip Ok, thank you. I will check it out, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Simon It doesn't really matter to me, to be honest. It seems it would be easier if it was reset though.

Comment: You could simply make the sensor check a function that is used by t_sensors and t_checker, so that t_sensors use it on a schedule and t_checker does it when it wants to. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I chose to avoid threads altogether... I found they were unnecessary. Instead, I passed the value of `refresh_rate` to `check_for_plants()` from `start_sensors()`, and then it slept in increments of 2 seconds until the time was up, or called `start_sensors()` if an event occurred. Thank you so much for all the help!